# linker error when archiving ios app with integrated facebook SDK

Tags: ios, swift, linker-errors, facebook-sdk-4.0

- I have an IOS app in swift which works fine.
- I have integrated Facebook SDK into my App and the common tests worked fine. I can run the app on my IPad and in the Simulator
- I had first linking error during building the app. I solved this by adding the path of the FacebookSDK Frameworks to the "Framework Search Paths" in the "Build Settings".
- My frameworks are added to the project for linking:

[image]

So far so good, but:
When archiving the app for submitting in apple store I get a linker error. I already cleaned the project and rebuilded which worked. Also analysing the app worked. Only archiving throws an error :

```
Ld /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ezoabbyxtblpfughttvlaqtuxxeb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/WORLDHISTORY_ATLAS/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/myapp.build/Release-iphoneos/WHatl.build/Objects-normal/armv7/WHatl normal armv7
    cd /Users/user/Desktop/Prototypes
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk -L/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ezoabbyxtblpfughttvlaqtuxxeb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/WORLDHISTORY_ATLAS/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ezoabbyxtblpfughttvlaqtuxxeb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/WORLDHISTORY_ATLAS/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/user/Documents/FacebookSDKs-iOS-4 -filelist /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ezoabbyxtblpfughttvlaqtuxxeb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/WORLDHISTORY_ATLAS/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/myapp.build/Release-iphoneos/WHatl.build/Objects-normal/armv7/WHatl.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=8.1 -dead_strip -fembed-bitcode -Xlinker -bitcode_verify -Xlinker -bitcode_hide_symbols -Xlinker -bitcode_symbol_map -Xlinker /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ezoabbyxtblpfughttvlaqtuxxeb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/WORLDHISTORY_ATLAS/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ezoabbyxtblpfughttvlaqtuxxeb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/WORLDHISTORY_ATLAS/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/myapp.build/Release-iphoneos/WHatl.build/Objects-normal/armv7/WHatl.swiftmodule -lz -framework FBSDKCoreKit -framework FBSDKShareKit -framework FBSDKLoginKit -lsqlite3 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ezoabbyxtblpfughttvlaqtuxxeb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/WORLDHISTORY_ATLAS/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/myapp.build/Release-iphoneos/WHatl.build/Objects-normal/armv7/WHatl_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ezoabbyxtblpfughttvlaqtuxxeb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/WORLDHISTORY_ATLAS/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/myapp.build/Release-iphoneos/WHatl.build/Objects-normal/armv7/WHatl

ld: warning: Auto-Linking supplied '/Users/user/Documents/FacebookSDKs-iOS-4/Bolts.framework/Bolts', framework linker option at /Users/user/Documents/FacebookSDKs-iOS-4/Bolts.framework/Bolts is not a dylib
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
```

any hints ? howto analyse ?

**UPDATE**

I have also added the Bolts.framework as like the other 3 frameworks. The app can still be built and run on the simulator and a device, but Archiving still throws am error but a different one :

```
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
```

any help ?

**UPDATE 2**

I guess I solved the problem. I modified the "Enable Bitcode" to "No" in the build settings. But I don't know what impacts this change can have.
Anyone knows ?

Comment: Have you tried deleting your project's derived data ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:
Select Xcode -> Go to Window option -> Select Projects -> Delete Derived data -> Quit Xcode -> Run your application again -> Archive the app

Comment: Thanks for helping. I can't follow you. I am in XCode, but cant find the option "Go to Window option".

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-general/Chapters/AbouttheOrganizerWindow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010548-CH2-SW1

Comment: Understood. But still didn't work. Running the app worked as before, but archiving the app still throws the same error.